# Metrics of embedded Undertow in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, metrics, graphite, undertow

I have spring boot 1.4.x and embedded Undertow 1.3.28. Some part of application monitored with Dropwizard MetricRegistry and metrics send to Graphite. I want to collect metrics from Undertow by MetricRegistry and send them to graphite as well. Metrics about Undertow threads, pool size, request count etc.

I found that i can customize Undertow by UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory in Spring boot, but i have no ideas how can i get server object ang get statistics from it. I found MetricsHandler in Undertow jar and i can add this handler to server handlers, but how to send info from this handler to MetricRegistry

Have anyone some practice with that?